# How to show staged files in "show history"?

Tags: intellij-idea

I was trying to commit a few files, but after I click the "commit" button, it asked me to review a file. Because of that, those staged files are not visible in 'show history'. In fact, "show history" was disabled. How to re-enable 'show history' view so that I can see the staged files again in 'show history'?

Comment: Would I be correct in assuming you just want to see git staging in IntelliJ ? as far as I know, this is currently not supported https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-63391

Answer (score 0):

The question is not clear. Could you please add a screenshot to clarify the issue?

Show history shows only committed data. If it was not committed, but only staged, it will not appear in the Show history.

Moreover, IntelliJ does not care about the stage at the moment, so from the IDE point of view, there is no difference between staged and non-staged files.

Comment: After I click "commit", the files shown in "local changes" tab in Show History disappeared, because it asked me to review files with warnings. I want to bring those disappearing files back to 'local changes' list.

Comment: Also, when a "push" fails, the file in "local changes" disappeared. How to bring it back?

Comment: So even not committed yet, files are not shown in Local changes tab as modified? Does Refresh icon help? Might be worth submitting an issue to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA